# I accidentally pressed Alt + Shift + F8 and my screen is gone on my desktop. How can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, display, keyboard-shortcuts

I have only one monitor. It displays that **this method of sync is not supported by the monitor please change the method of sync.**

My desktop only takes VGA and my monitor also. I have windows 10

Comment: Usually, press the same keyboard combination again. I do wonder though if its not fn-shift-f8

Comment: Hello, do you have Intel HD Graphics?

Comment: If the key combo doesn't switch this, you can usually get into Safe Mode, delete your display adapter, and then restart. The computer will probably reinstall the display adapter automatically, and the display should be reset.

Comment: @LPChip or ctrl-alt-f8 perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays